# How do I write a left join query?

Tags: 7, database

I want to get the value of "vid" knowing the node ID, and get the value of "name" for those rows where "vid" is equal to 2.

If it were a plain query, I would not know how to write it; I don't know how to write a left join query.

The "plain" SQL query in Drupal is the following:

```
$result = db_query('SELECT tid FROM {taxonomy_index} WHERE nid = :nid', array(':nid'=>$nid));
```

The equivalent raw SQL query is the following:

```sql
SELECT did, name FROM taxonomy_index as ti LEFT JOIN taxonomy_term_data AS ttd ON ti.tid = ttd.tid WHERE vid = 2 and nid = $nid
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You do not need to use db_select() for a static query like this. You shouldn't, actually, see [Given that db_select is much slower than db_query, why would I want to use it?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/given-that-db-select-is-much-slower-than-db-query-why-would-i-want-to-use-it).

You just need to pass that to db_query(), the only thing that changed is how you add placeholders.

```
$result = db_query('select tid,name from {taxonomy_index} as ti left join {taxonomy_term_data} as ttd on ti.tid=ttd.tid where vid=2 and nid=:nid', array(':nid' => $nid));
foreach ($result as $term) {
  // $term contains the object for the taxonomy term.
}
```

See http://drupal.org/developing/api/database for more information and [my blog post](http://blog.worldempire.ch/story/howto-convert-module-dbtng) for generic Drupal 6 to 7 database syntax conversion information.

Comment: many thanks. the link is very good. i have read it.but i still don't know what is a dynamic query?

Comment: A dynamic query is what Sivaji wrote: using db_select() to build a query with PHP code. useful for example when you have a query with different conditions based on something (configuration, permission, different pages.. )

Comment: on the above code,could i change vid=2 to vid=:vid then array(':vid' => 2)).should i necessary do this? thank you

Comment: It is not strictly necessary, but yes, it might make sense. Especially if you don't want to hardcode that vid but for example use variable_get() to make it overridable. so you would do `array(':vid' => variable_get('yourmodule_vocabulary', 2))`. Then it would default to 2, but you could override it in settings.php or build a admin settings form for it.

Comment: Yes. You need to do, `vid=2 to vid=:vid then array(':vid' => 2)` to keep your code compatible across the database servers. Drupal core follows the same pattern.

Answer (score 25):

```
$terms = db_select('taxonomy_index', 'ti')
  ->fields('ti', array('tid', 'name'));
$terms->leftJoin('taxonomy_term_data', 'ttd', 'ti.tid = ttd.tid');
$terms->condition('vid', 2)
  ->condition('nid', $nid)
  ->execute();

while ($term = $terms->fetch()) {
  // $term contains the object for the taxonomy term.
}
```

Comment: how to retrieve the result? thank you

Comment: Does this work? When I try to do something identical to this I get an error that condition() is not a member function.

Comment: This won't work. Drupal joins can't be chained. So you'd go: `$terms = db_select(...)->fields(...); $terms->leftJoin(...); $terms->condition(...)->...`

Comment: @Neograph734 I suggested an edit based on your comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
        $catalog_pagination = db_select('taxonomy_index', 'ti')
          ->fields('pimg',array('uc_product_image_target_id','entity_id'))
          ->fields('fm',array('fid','filename'))    
          ->fields('ti', array('nid', 'tid'));
        $catalog_pagination->leftJoin('node__uc_product_image', 'pimg', 'pimg.entity_id = ti.nid'); 
        $catalog_pagination->leftJoin('file_managed', 'fm', 'fm.fid = pimg.uc_product_image_target_id');  
        $catalog_pagination->condition('ti.tid', $term_id);
        $catalog_pagination->orderBy('ti.nid', 'DESC');
        $catalog_pagination = $catalog_pagination->execute();
        $total_pages = $catalog_pagination->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score -1):

//Don't forget "fetchAll()" function:

```
$terms = db_select('taxonomy_index', 'ti')
  ->fields('ti', array('tid', 'name'));
$terms->leftJoin('taxonomy_term_data', 'ttd', 'ti.tid = ttd.tid');
$terms->condition('vid', 2)
  ->condition('nid', $nid)
  ->execute()
  **->fetchAll();** // an array of objects

**$i = 0;
while ($i < count($terms)) {
  $terms[i]->...
  // $terms[i] contains the object for the taxonomy term.
  $i++;
}**
```