# How do I connect to the database from a module?

Tags: 7, theming

I would like to connect to the database from a Drupal 7 module. Currently I only have the query I want to run which is:

```
$query = db_select('z_lists)
->fields('country')
->condition('value', $country, '=')
->execute()
->fetchAssoc();
```

What I can't figure out is how to establish a connection to the default database.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just execute the query, Drupal takes care of everything else.

If it doesn't work, then that's for another reason.

Also, see [Given that db_select is much slower than db_query, why would I want to use it?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/given-that-db-select-is-much-slower-than-db-query-why-would-i-want-to-use-it)