# Select fields from two tables using db_select()

Tags: database

I am using `db_select()` and I don't understand the syntax of the `fields()` method. I'm using a `join()` to join another table. So for tables `t` and `n`, I want to do something like

```
SELECT t.tid, t.field1, t.field2, n.title, n.author 
FROM table t INNER JOIN node n ON t.nid = n.nid;
```

I have

```
$results = db_select('table', 't')
  ->fields( ... )
  ->join('node', 'n', 'n.nid = t.nid')
  ->execute();
```

But as you can see, I'm lost at `fields()`. The examples I've seen only specify fields for one table:

```
->fields('t', array('tid', 'field1', 'field2'))
```

What is the syntax that I want to use?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Easy, just call fields() twice.

```
$query = db_select('table', 't');
$query->join('node', 'n', 'n.nid = t.nid');
$result = $query
  ->fields('t', array('tid', 'field1', 'field2'))
  ->fields('n', array('nid', 'field1', 'field2'))
  ->execute();

foreach ($result as $row) {
  // Do something with $row.
}
```

You can call most methods multiple times (multiple fields, multiple conditions, multiple sort orders, multiple joins, ...).

Note that, as shown in my example, the call to join() needs to be separate and can not be "chained" (that's the technical term for having multiple method calls in a row) because it does not return the query object but the name for the table alias.

Answer (score 2):

An implicit join will still work with db_query(), if you're not doing anything fancy.  I'm not sure if this is bad practice or not though.  I asked once in IRC and didn't get a response from anyone.  So if you've got any of those left over from D6, they'll still work.

Comment: Using db_query() is perfectly fine (It's actually recommended for performance reasons) unless there is a explicit reason for using db_select(). I've outlined those reasons here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/given-that-db-select-is-much-slower-than-db-query-why-would-i-want-to-use-it

Comment: Great! I was too lazy to convert mine anyway. ;)