# Query with db_select() to select node by id and join field and terms

Tags: database

I am trying to write a query using db_select that selects a particular node by id, and then joins it's field_data_field_projectresources column and also selects the terms from taxonomy (because this is a term_reference field)

I have tried numerous attempts but I am finding myself stuck (I didn't even get to the part about joining the  dr_taxonomy_term_data table)

```
 $query = db_select('node','n')
  ->condition('n.nid','5')
  ->fields('n')
  ->fields('p');
 $query->Join('field_data_field_projectresources','p','p.entity_id = n.nid');
 $result = $query->execute();

 while($record = $result->fetchAssoc()) {
   print_r($record);
 }
```

Any help appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Can use: '$result = db_query("SELECT dr_node.nid, dr_node.title as 'title', dr_taxonomy_term_data.name  as 'resourceterm'
FROM dr_node
JOIN dr_field_data_field_projectresources ON dr_node.nid = dr_field_data_field_projectresources.entity_id
JOIN dr_taxonomy_term_data ON dr_field_data_field_projectresources.field_projectresources_tid = dr_taxonomy_term_data.tid
WHERE dr_node.nid = '5'");
?>
Resources for why make</br>
<?php
foreach ($result as $row) {
 print $row->resourceterm;
 ?><br/><?php
    }'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I hope this works for you:

```
 $query = db_select('node','n');
 $query->join('field_data_field_projectresources','p','p.entity_id = n.nid');
 $query->fields('n',array('yourfieldnames'))
       ->fields('p',array('yourfieldnames'))
       ->condition('n.nid','5');
 $result = $query->execute();
```

Here is [another answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6921/select-fields-from-two-tables-using-db-select) that will help you very much.

Check out documentation for 'join' on [drupal.org](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3Ajoin/7).

Comment: The `join` method isn't chainable unfortunately, so it must be on it's own line.